# What is the data contained in ROS topic velodyne_msgs/VelodynePacket Message?

Tags: ros, robotics, lidar

I am doing a light weight program to monitor received beams for lidar. Preferably, I do not want to cache the entire UDP data packet or point cloud data due to the light weight nature.

The question is what is the data contained in ROS message velodyne_msgs/VelodynePacket. This message contains smaller data but I do not know if it is related.

By read the [Ros Wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_msgs) on this topic but the link for velodynepackt did not provide useful info on the content.

Answer (score -1):

Check the message definition to see what fields a message contains and their types. Message files will usually either have field names that are self explanatory or will have comments (`## text`) describing the fields. You can look at the message definitions either online or locally. To look at them locally use `roscd` to get to the package directory `roscd <package_name>/msg` and then using `cat` to see the contents of the message file. In your case, this would be:

`roscd velodyne_msgs/msg
cat VelodynePacket.msg
cat VelodyneScan.msg`

The relevant message files are available online from the page you linked to:
http://docs.ros.org/api/velodyne_msgs/html/msg/VelodyneScan.html
http://docs.ros.org/api/velodyne_msgs/html/msg/VelodynePacket.html

In regards to your specific question about creating a lightweight application, you have a few options.

1. Use the provided ROS message and subscribe to it. Most of the time if you don't have a ton of large data traveling around, you'll be okay and will be able to keep up with real time data. The majority of the time associated with ROS usually comes from the network transport, so if that's a problem, you'll need to not pass the data over ROS.
2. Put your code in a ROS Nodelet. This gives you the advantages of ROS data abstractions while eliminating the network data transfer that occurs between nodes. This is akin to using a pointer to the data field.
3. If you really don't want all the scan data, but still want to use ROS, you can write your own driver node. This will read from the LIDAR the data you want and discard the data you don't. You can do the raw data processing in that node (no ROS message required) or publish the data you care about and do the processing in another node.

Comment: This answer is really helpful in the respect of further going down the road. But, the VelodynePacket.msg only indicates the unit8[1206] data but now what they are.

Comment: Downvoted because it doesn't address the question at all.